# Comparing two rows in the same table in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have looked at similar answers but, this is what I am looking for since I did not find any answers from previously answered questions:

This is my scenario: I have a table `[res_user]` with `username, password, key_pin` which saves a username, an encrypted password, and a 4 digit pin or key.

I am making an app in C# that allows a manager to log in and make changes to the database from the app itself.

The manager is first prompted to log in with a username, a password, and their key_pin they are provided with. The pin is what will encrypt and decrypt the password to and from the database.

Now I have a username `[manager]` and an encrypted password already saved in the database with the `key_pin`.

How can I make sure that the manager logging in is the right one, meaning how can I compare the username and the encrypted password in the database from the C# app.

These are the steps that I though of that I will implement in the app itself (using SQL syntax in c#):

1. Encrypt the password,
2. Get the saved encryption in the database using the login username, and
3. **Compare** the encryption returning a yes or a no back to the app for access control.

allowing 5 attempts to log in.

This is the first and second part I did:

```
try
{
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["STRING"].ConnectionString))
   {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Res_User", con))
     {
       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Res_User(username, password, key_pin) SELECT '" + username + "' , dbo.fnEncDecRc4('" + pin + "','" + password + "'), '" + pin + "'";
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       MessageBox.Show("Added", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT password FROM Res_User WHERE username = @username";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           if (reader.HasRows)
           {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                    MessageBox.Show(reader["password"].ToString(), "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
               }
           }
       }
```

How do I go about doing the third part?

Only if someone can help me compare the saved enc. password and the login enc. password which I did in part one.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thank You.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Once you encrypt the password and store it in the database, you use an algorithm to decrypt the password and compare it with what they have entered.  Then return a `bool`.

Comment: Why not use a c# library to encrypt/decrypt, that way the comparison would be easier to implement (in c#, rather than SQL) and as a side benefit the plain-text password would not sent between the app and the database.

Comment: Watch out for sql injection and shouldn't you be better with hashed passwords, instead of encrypting and decryptiong them?

Comment: @paul The reason is that I have to use a SQL databse and also, this is the first time I am using C#. I have only worked on java and SQL connections but, not on C#. I just want to know if there is a SQL statement that I can use to see if the password input in login is the password in the databse for the username used. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try re-encrypting the password and pin on the server when you're doing validation on the server.  So that you will call your encrypt function, then do a comparison and if you have results, you know that the correct password was entered.  Modifying your code, it would look like:

```
try
{
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["STRING"].ConnectionString))
   {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Res_User", con))
     {
       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Res_User(username, password, key_pin) SELECT '" + username + "' , dbo.fnEncDecRc4('" + pin + "','" + password + "'), '" + pin + "'";
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       MessageBox.Show("Added", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT password FROM Res_User WHERE username = @username AND key_pin = @pin AND password = dbo.fnEncDecRc4(@pin, @password)";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", pin);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           if (reader.HasRows)
           {
               //successfully validated.
           }
       }
```

Comment: How can I compare the encrypted passwords ? what is the sql statement for that ?

Comment: It's really up to you on what you think the app should do.  You'll know that the passwords match, and you'll have a hashed password, so you can do whatever you want from there.

Comment: Nevermind fixed it. You used pin insted key_pin. But I don't get where is your code checking for equal values? I already have a username password and a key_pin in the database, and when the user inputs a login credential I want to check and see if the password matches with the given username.

So, it woud be something like this: in the databse i have username = manager, password = enrypted password, and key_pin = given pin.

when manager tries to log on I want to take their input values and compare with the values in database. If they match, then access granted. else not.

Comment: The SELECT that does the verification uses a WHERE clause to select rows where the username, encrypted password, and pin values match.  It will only return a result if all three of those criteria match.  So  if(reader.HasRows) will only be true if user entered in the correct username, password, and pin.